# Can Random(Int32).Next(minValue, maxValue) be used as a Linear Congruential Generator?

Tags: c#

Can

```
 System.Random(Int32).Next(minValue, maxValue) ;
```

be used as a sort of Linear Congruential Generator?

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer is NO. Because Random() changes from version to version in .NET. I cannot use Random(Int32).Next(minValue, maxValue) as a sort of Linear Congruential Generator. Ugh!

Comment: you have to compile your code targeting a specific version of .Net, so your program will always be with the same implementation of Random unless you change the target framework and re-compile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, System.Random will always give the same next value given the same seed and boundaries, the constant is the seed which you can optionally supply. So you would NOT want to change the seed each time you call Next() as your line does, instead:

```
var myRandom = new Random(mySeed);
var value = myRandom.Next(minValue, maxValue);
var anotherValue = myRandom.Next(minValue, maxValue);
...
```

Comment: Be aware that the implementation of Random has changed multiple times in the past. That means the same seed gives different random numbers on different .NET Framework versions. Most likely it will give different numbers again when .NET 5 is released someday.

Comment: To continue on what Felheart said, if you want to avoid the chance that the internal implmentation will change causing a new sequence for the same seed use a RNG with a well defined behavior. A easy way to do this is just use any of the Crypto stream chipers and read the stream of bytes you get out from a given key.